# Document has become very large and slow

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

Currently I'm using MS Word 2013 for daily reporting in work place but after a few months, it has become around 600 pages and its size is 77MB. Every time I want to save MS Word file, it takes a while because MS Word file is on network not my local computer and also it contains lots of pictures and drawings. I wonder if there is any way to make MS Word file faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to split the document.

Files with lots of contents will be big and thus will take long to save. You could for example use one file for each month. It will not only solve your problem, but also protect you from accidentally deleting old parts of the file (there's less to delete).

If you really want to keep number of files low, then you could convert Word files to PDF at the end of each month and merge it with previous PDF using [PDFTK Builder](http://www.angusj.com/pdftkb/#pdftkbuilder).